# Where to get info about the themes and xml attributes

Tags: android, xml

Here in this code below

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
</style>
```

Where do I get the info about the attribute `android:actionMenuTextColor`, etc. and how will I know that I have to use this attribute here.

Comment: Where do I get the info about the attribute android:actionMenuTextColor etc. and how will I know that I have to use this attribute here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation about the property **[actionMenuTextColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#actionMenuTextColor)**:

> Color for text that appears within action menu items.
>
> May be a reference to another resource, in the form
>   "@[+][package:]type:name" or to a theme attribute in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name".
>
> May be a color value, in the form of "#rgb", "#argb", "#rrggbb", or
>   "#aarrggbb".

Here you can find examples
**[Styling the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)**

Comment: Thanks!! But can you tell me from where do I know which attributes to use under a particular theme

Comment: check the reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles  and the file Themes.xml https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml